# find the standard basis of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\beta =\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be a basis for the vector space V and let $T:V\to R^2$ be a transformation with the property that
$$T(x_1b_1 + x_2b_x + x_3b_3) = \begin{bmatrix}
2x_1-3x_2+x_3\\
-2x_1+5x_3\end{bmatrix}$$
Find the matrix for T relative to $\beta$ and the standard matrix for T

I found $[T]_\beta$
$$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3 & 1\\
-2& 0 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The next thing I need to do to find the matrix T relative to the standard matrix. To find $[T]_\beta$ I analised $T(x_1b_1 + x_2b_x + x_3b_3)$ into 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
T(b_1) & T(b_2) & T(b_3)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where
$$\begin{bmatrix}
T(b_1) & T(b_2) & T(b_3)\end{bmatrix} = [T]_\beta$$

Now, what I need to do to find the T relative to the standard basis for $R^2$. Please guide me.